# How to write a complex reference to objects in email templates for Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I need to create a reference in an email template. for that I need to reffer a standard **Contact** objecect. For that I have a Custom Object **Email Info**, that has a lokup to standard **Accounts**.

So in the email I have to have value of the custom field **Email_info__c** from the custom object **Email_info__c**(the object and it's field have the same API names) while entering the **Contact**.

In the end both **Contacts** and my custom object have the lookups to **Account**, but not to each other, and there is no lookup from **Acount**, for now.

My first guess was to refer to the first child object **Email info** in the header of the VF template

```
relatedToType="Email_Info__c"
```

and then refer to it in the body as

```
{!RelatedTo.Account_r}
```

but then I would need a lookup from **Accounts** to **Email Info** to be able to refer deeper

```
 {!RelatedTo.Account_r.Email_Info__r.Email_Info__c}
```

but, I don't think that it'll work that way or that it meets the needed criteria. Can someone share if there is an option at all to get the **Email Info** to **Contacts** through **Accounts** without creating a lookup on **Accounts**?

The task is to have a middle referred object, not a direct lookup:

[image]

Comment: A small drawing would help us understand or maybe setup->schema builder screenshot. Is there relation between contact and email info? Have you tried `relatedto.account__r.emailinfos__r[0].name`? Worst case you could make a small vf component, give it a controller and run queries in it?

Comment: added a schema builder screenshot. as you can see there is no direct relationship between the email info and a contact, and they both are having a lookup to account onl, but not in return. so in this case will the expresion account_r.emailinfo_r work? and what does the number in [ ] means for that expression? I would consider it as a record number in a list, if it was JS or Java, or any other normal programming language, but in case of Salesforce I can't understand what would it reffer to? Could you please explain? Also, how would a controller with a querry look like in the email template?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit how you are going to use this email template. What will the send be triggered from. Account? Contact? Email Info record? Will it be fired from a workflow or user will be instructed to navigate to account record and start composing the message?

If your `relatedTo` is really `Email_Info__c` then you don't have to do anything, you have all the data hidden in `{!relatedTo.Id}, {!relatedTo.Name}, {!relatedTo.Email_Info__c}` (you said the field name is same as object's name)

If your email starts from "Account" and you can guarantee accounts will have 1 email info record on related list - something like this might work:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="hi stack" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Account">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
{!relatedTo.Opportunities[0].Id} {!relatedTo.Opportunities[0].Name} {!relatedTo.Opportunities[0].StageName} {!relatedTo.Opportunities[0].CloseDate}
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

from Account (relatedTo) I'm going down to the related list of Opportunities, I'm picking 1st one (at random... but if you have just 1 record it'll be fine) and display whatever I want.

If your relatedTo and recipient both have to be Contact it starts to get bit messier, normal visualforce syntax will not allow you to go "up" (from Contact to Account) and then "down" (from Account to related list of email infos)

You'd need to start with something like https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_with_apex.htm and then figure out how to pass the Id of account to it and run a query for email infos related to this account. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245930/pass-id-from-visualforce-email-template-to-controller might be a good start, poke me if you're stuck.